# Get the server name and ip address in C# 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, ip, ip-address

Get the server name and ip address in C# 2010

I want to get the IP address of the server. The following code comes from:

```
public static void DoGetHostEntry(string hostname)
{

        IPHostEntry host;

        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname);

        MessageBox.Show("GetHostEntry({0}) returns:"+ hostname);

        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("    {0}"+ ip.ToString());
        }
}
```

This code must know the name of the server computer.
AddressFamily in System.Net.IPAddress

`System.Net.IPAddress i;`
`string HostName = i.AddressFamily.ToString();`

Error ------------->Use of unassigned local variable 'i'

How can I get the name of the server computer?

Comment: You need to update your question to more accurately describe what you are asking (move comments from the answer to the question).

Comment: I have software on your local network. There is only one server in the network.
This software may be installed on many local area network. And make use of it.
I want to install and run in any location; Automatically detect the server computer on the local network.;;;;I do not have the server's IP and computer name. And I want them to get a special code.;;;;The server is the computer name and IP address. On the client computer, the server will recognize. And return the IP address or name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    public string[] ServerName()
    {
        string[] strIP = DisplayIPAddresses();
        int CountIP = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < strIP.Length; i++)
        {
            if (strIP[i] != null)
                CountIP++;
        }
        string[] name = new string[CountIP];
        for (int i = 0; i < strIP.Length; i++)
        {
            if (strIP[i] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    name[i] = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strIP[i]).HostName;
                }
                catch
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        return name;
    }


    public string[] DisplayIPAddresses()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Get a list of all network interfaces (usually one per network card, dialup, and VPN connection)     
        NetworkInterface[] networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

        int i = -1;
        string[] s = new string[networkInterfaces.Length];

        foreach (NetworkInterface network in networkInterfaces)
        {
            i++;
            if (network.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                if (network.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Tunnel) continue;
                if (network.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Tunnel) continue;
                //GatewayIPAddressInformationCollection GATE = network.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses;
                // Read the IP configuration for each network   

                IPInterfaceProperties properties = network.GetIPProperties();
                //discard those who do not have a real gateaway 
                if (properties.GatewayAddresses.Count > 0)
                {
                    bool good = false;
                    foreach (GatewayIPAddressInformation gInfo in properties.GatewayAddresses)
                    {
                        //not a true gateaway (VmWare Lan)
                        if (!gInfo.Address.ToString().Equals("0.0.0.0"))
                        {
                            s[i] = gInfo.Address.ToString();
                            good = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!good)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the host name you can do the following:

```
string name = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
```

If you want the hostname and (first IPv4) IP of your computer use the following:

```
string name = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(name);
System.Net.IPAddress ip = host.AddressList.Where(n => n.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork).First();
```

The name and the ip will hold the info for the local computer.

The server could then send out the ip via a udp multicast and the client on the network would just join a known multicast address that is not specific to the server.

multicast [example](http://www.jarloo.com/c-udp-multicasting-tutorial/).

Comment: How to get the IP?
The name comes from the computer's IP address.
I have no IP and not computer name server.

Comment: You want the name of a computer that you don't have an IP or Name?

Comment: Not. The server is the computer name and IP address.
On the client computer, the server will recognize. And return the IP address or name.

Comment: How is the client going to contact the server if it does not know the name or address of the server?

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.
I do not have the server's IP and computer name. And I want them to get a special code.

Comment: There are millions of "Servers" in the world and you want your client to magically find "Your Server" without knowing any information about the server. Thats some special code for sure!

Comment: Excuse
I have software on your local network. There is only one server in the network.
This software may be installed on many local area network. And make use of it.
I want to install and run in any location; Automatically detect the server computer on the local network.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to figure out for yourself that error(unassigned local variable) and learn why it is coming(it is very basic), before looking for some magical code that will do the job for you.

And secondly, there is no magical code. I am no socket programmer but it seems to me that in your application running on the client machines, you need to hardcode the name of your server. If you don't want to do that, program in such a way that only your server machine will listen on a particular port and all client machines will listen on a different port. Thus, each machine in the LAN can enumerate over the available machines and establish/determine the client server connection/relation for the first time. and that approach is still very ugly unless you are writing a virus or something.